# Using JQuery select child element of the given parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a panelbar there are many list items `<li>` (let's say parent items). Every list item has different number of list items (child items).

```
$(".childItem:nth-child("1");
```

This method will select all the first child items of all the parent items. 
How can I select with jQuery the child item of the parent item I need?

Comment: So to be clear, you only want to select the first child element? The outcome you want would be clearer to understand if you added the HTML and detailed which elements you do/do not want to select

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: The jQuery example provided is invalid.

Comment: if the element's selector is a distinct one, the ```elt = $(selector)``` will return one single element. If it isn't distinct, it will return a list. You can select the specific element by going ```elt[n]```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .childItem:nth-of-type(x), where **x** are the child you want select.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Answer (score 0):

While I will show a JQuery solution, this is such a simple thing that JQuery really is overkill.

```js
$("ul.list:first-of-type > li:first-of-type").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>
```